# Unable to find module after import

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-module

I'm runnin Python 3.6.3 and I have the following module in a subdirectory that I'm trying to install through pip.

```
/g_plotter
          setup.py
          /g_plotter
                    __init__.py
                    g_plotter.py
                    Gparser.py
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='g_plotter',
    packages=['g_plotter'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'flask',
    ],
)
```

I installed that module form Docker in my container:

```
RUN pip3 install ./g_plotter
```

Then in my app code:

```
import g_plotter

print(dir(g_plotter))
```

which outputs

```
 server_1  | ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

so using this import instead:

```
from  g_plotter import g_plotter
```

results in

```
server_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
server_1  |   File "./g_server.py", line 21, in <module>
server_1  |     from  g_plotter import g_plotter
server_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/g_plotter/g_plotter.py", line 7, in <module>
server_1  |     import Gparser
server_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gparser'
```

When I run the submodule on it's own (It's a flask app), it works.

Comment: Your structure is wrong. For example to import `Gparser`, you should write `from g_plotter import Gparser` as it is in a module.

Comment: @Sraw, then in the flask app when running it directly I get "ImportError: cannot import name 'Gparser' from 'g_plotter'".  And in my main app, it also errors out with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gparser'"

Comment: This is because your design is wrong... It's a little bit hard to explain in comment. But basically you can image that when you directly run your package inside the package, the directories structure doesn't contain your package top directory. But when you use it as a package, the directories structure will contain your package's directory. I don't know if it is clear enough... Essentially is package has an additional wrapper directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use absolute import in python 3, `import Gparser` is not allowed any more. You can change it to:

```
from . import Gparser
from g_plotter import Gparser
```

Let you more clear, I will describe what do they mean.

`import Gparser`

```
Gparser = load_module()
sys.modules['Gparser'] = Gparser
```

`from g_plotter import Gparser`

```
Gparser = load_module()
sys.modules[Gparser_name] = Gparser
```

`from . import Gparser`

```
package = find_package(__name__)  # 'g_plotter'
Gparser_name = package + 'Gparser'  # g_plotter.Gparser
Gparser = load_module()
sys.modules[Gparser_name] = Gparser
```

Now you can understand, if you run g_plotter directly, actually `__name__` is `__main__`, so python can't find a package from it. Only if you import this submodule in other module, `from . import something` can be worked.

Comment: these aren't working for me.  Running the submodule directly from the command line gives me: "    from . import Gparser
ImportError: cannot import name 'Gparser"

Comment: @user994165 You can't use `from . import something` in main module. This statement must be used in one package.

Comment: OK.  I moved the submodule script to the root level and changed the import to "from g_plotter import Gparser", and used the same import in the app.